# My text is cropped when exporting using lyx

Tags: math-mode, arrays

When i'm exporting my lyx to pdf (or even when running the latex code) my text is cropped :
[image]

Tried playing with document setting but could not find any thing there. any idea?
Here the code from latex :

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Here is a test , im' writing things and adding things like : $U=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 5 & -4 & -10\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 2 & -4 & -8
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-2R_{3}}{R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}-R_{3}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 5 & -10 & -20\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 2 & -4 & -8
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-5R_{2}}{R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}-2R_{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\Leftrightarrow R_{3}}{R_{2}\Leftrightarrow R_{4}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$and another $U=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 5 & -4 & -10\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 2 & -4 & -8
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-2R_{3}}{R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}-R_{3}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 5 & -10 & -20\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 2 & -4 & -8
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-5R_{2}}{R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}-2R_{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\tbinom{R_{1}\Leftrightarrow R_{3}}{R_{2}\Leftrightarrow R_{4}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of a screenshot would be useful. Nevertheless, it seems that you have a [problem with line-breaking in math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode+line-breaking?sort=votes&pageSize=15). I would recommend to use displayed math instead of inline math for such things.

Comment: @Schweinebacke ,  i have updated the questions ! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a LyX problem, nor a LaTeX one. Your formulas are simply too long to be kept in line. You should display them, for a start (Menu `Insert/Math/Display formula` in LyX). If they are still too long, there is still the possibility of breaking them in several lines (`Insert/Math/Align-gather-multline`…)

Comment: Thank you! display formula worked well together with divide my formulas into two rows.